# Ubuntu netboot installer point to point (peer) Network

Tags: networking, system-installation, ubuntu-minimal, configure, debian-installer

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 Netboot (minimal), but in my network i have peer ip address instead of Getaway.
and ubuntu installer just ask for getaway and no option or choice for peer ip address instead of Gateway.

when network config is finishing  i can see `point to point = <none>`
but i dont know how to set it. please help me.
also i used kernel parameter `netcfg/get_pointopoint=1.2.3.4` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by doing :

1- first config network manually and set random ip address like 1.3.4.5 this can be any value and next set random netmask like 255.255.255.0 and leave Gateway blank

2- set nameservers like 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8

3 continue to choose mirror archive and select country... then you get bad archive mirror error

4- go back to installer main menu and execute a shell

5- run this following command :

```
# ip addr add <ip-address>/32 peer <peer-address> dev <interface-name>
# ip route add defualt via <peer-address>
```

6- execute debian-installer by running this command : `debian-installer`

7- in menu select choose a mirror of ubuntu archive and you are good to go ...

note : you should run the installer in expert mode